# How to set IIS rewrite rule for CORS?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, cors, cross-domain, iis-10

I created an IIS rewrite role for a server url.

When I send request to `[https://mysite/back/api/....][1]`, it will get data from `https://remotesite/back/api/....`

So my IIS rewrite config is like following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="api">
                    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="`https://remotesite/back/api/{R:1}`" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
          <outboundRules>
              <clear />                
              <rule name="api">
                  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                      <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(.*)" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
              </rule>           
          </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But the `[https://mydomain/back/api/][1]` has a "Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin". So I can not send a javascript request to my domain.

How can I update the config?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [IIS CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) to solve this problem. For information about "IIS CORS module Configuration Reference", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference).